# JUnit with Kotlin - This class does not have a constructor

Tags: java, testing, junit, kotlin

I'm trying to implement testing with JUnit4 in my Kotlin application (as `kotlin.test` seems to be nonexistent in my Kotlin Runtime Library, and I don't now how to get it).
However, I am encountering an error simply by using the `Test` annotation.
That's my code:

```
import junit.framework.*

class IntTest {
    @Test    <------------- This line
    fun test1() {

    }
}
```

On the specified line, Eclipse gives an error message: `"This class does not have a constructor"`.
I don't understand what is the problem. Which class doesn't have a constructor, and why should it have one?

Comment: try adding `import org.junit.Test;`

Answer (score 6):

The [junit.framework.Test](https://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/Test.html) is an interface and it's implementation has been [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityTestCase.html) since API 24. Since it's an interface hence it is causing the error

```
"This class does not have a constructor".
```

during annotation processing which is actually looking for a class.

Solution : Remove this and use `import org.junit.Test;`

Answer (score 0):

A little bit old this question. But I ran into the same problem recently.
I got the same error in Intellij Idea.

The building tool I'm using is gradle. And to setup the testing dependencies I followed the instruction on the kotlinlang site: [Test code using Junit in JVM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-test-using-junit.html)

The tests run fine but in the IDE I see these same errors.

I could fix this by changing the dependency from:

```
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.5.21'
```

to:

```
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5:1.5.21'
```

This actually added the Junit 5 dependency. Which I think is necessary as you might have to choose which underlying test framework you want to use for `kotlin.test`.

Edit: In my test I import `import kotlin.test.Test` like in the Tutorial.